# Как обратится к объекту который вызвал событие Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как обратится к объекту который вызвал событие, допустим, у меня есть событие при вводе символа , как мне обратится к той строке в которую был введен символ. Нужно для того чтобы сделать один обработчик для всех компонентов (в данном случае для `TextField`) .

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обработчике события, которому передается параметр event, вызови метод `event.getSource()`, если я не ошибся в написании. Он вернёт объект, который вызвал событие.